# Is this kind of speedup with CUDA to be expected?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, cuda

I am comparing `blas` with `cublas` and I'm getting some mind blowing results.

The cpu I am using is a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2` at `2.8 GHz` and I am running my matrix multiplications with `cblas_dgemm` on increasingly larger sizes of matrices.

The gpu I am using is a `Nvidia K40` with 15 multiprocessors, warp size of 32, and 480 `CUDA` cores (advertised as 2880 `CUDA` cores [here](http:////http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-servers.html)). The clock speed is `0.71 GHz` and I am using `cublasDgemm` for matrix multiplications.

I have done a runtime analysis and shown that the `K40` is `~12.48%` faster than the `K80` for large matrix operations which is about what I expected. I am showing that the `K40` is about `8000%` faster than a single threaded CPU matrix dot product and this is a whole lot faster than I expected, so I suspect something is amiss.

NOTE: I am testing with `100` iterations and averaging the runs, but I am counting *only* calls to the respective `*gemm` functions. I am intentionally leaving out memory allocation time on the `cpu` and `gpu` since I want to test how fast things can go *after* the `cpu` to `gpu` data transfer has completed. Given this information, is `80x` speedup plausible?

Comment: There are 480 GPU cores running against one CPU core. Why would a speedup of 80 be suspicious? As Anastasiya points out, you could tune the CPU version - for instance, make it parallel - and you could see that go down.

Comment: It's probably plausible given your test case. The  cblas_dgemm you are using is probably not at all optimized for the Intel processor you are using, whereas cublas is well-optimized for the K40 or K80. Try using Intel MKL, or another good blas implementation such as OpenBLAS or gotoBLAS.  Certainly you should use Intel MKL to get the best CPU numbers on an intel CPU.  In order to get good performance from the Intel CPU, you must use a multithreaded code **and** take advantage of AVX.  My guess is your clbas_dgemm is doing niether.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella - this is what I expected. I have intel compilers and have optimized `c++` code with `avx` and multithreading before to great avail, but was intentionally trying to compare a 'naive' implementation and was surprised it was this drastic.

Comment: If you ran a naive matrix multiply on the GPU and compared it to cublas, for some comparisons you would also find the difference to be "drastic".  K40 has 2880 CUDA cores, but these are effectively SP (single precision) units.  The correct number for estimation purposes on dense double-precision compute codes would be 1/3 of that number (not 480), i.e. 960.  This 960 number plus a few other specs (e.g. clock rate) would be what is used to compute the peak theoretical throughput of the K40 GPU (on double-precision).

Comment: By the way, if you are benchmarking K40, be sure to use boosted clocks.  This can be accomplished with `nvidia-smi`.  K80 has an "autoboost" feature, so it should be less dependent on manual clock fiddling.

Comment: You do understand that CUBLAS calls are asynchronous? And you are using a suitable host-device synchronization call in your timing?

Comment: @talonmies I am using `cudaThreadSynchronize()` and `cublasGetVector()` on each iteration of the trials. That should perform adequate host-device synchronization, right?

Comment: @Laurbert515: Yes that should be ok. I ask because we have no code and  large number of these sorts of questions arise because of a lack of understanding about which API calls are asynchronous, and/or incorrect timing. If you calculate a FLOP number for the BLAS call, what do you get?

Comment: My hd7870 is 180 to 240 times faster than my fx8150's single core for 8200 x 8200 sgemm (over 1 Tflops), pci-e transports included.

Comment: That Xeon CPU has 8 cores with 2 threads per core and you are only using one thread in total. As others have already implied, If you split that task into 16 parallel threads in an optimized way then the difference against the GPU will be much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

80x speedup is plausible.  I think you could witness something like that in *any* of the following cases:

1. dgemm on CPU using cblas in a single thread, and comparing to intel MKL dgemm
2. dgemm on CPU using cblas in a single thread, and comparing to cublas dgemm
3. naive GPU matrix multiply, and comparing to cublas dgemm

In each case, the comparison is between unoptimized code and optimized code.

In the case of an Intel CPU, two key factors to get high performance are to use multiple threads (to engage most or all of the cores) and to use AVX (to engage the vector processing unit(s)).  It's possible that your cblas dgemm isn't doing this, and so will run quite slowly.  cublas dgemm will use the GPU efficiently, and in the case of an intel CPU, MKL dgemm will use the CPU efficiently.

Whenever possible, whether programming on the GPU or the CPU, you should use libraries and especially for operations like matrix multiply or FFT, where the underlying efficient realization is difficult to achieve.  Intel [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), or perhaps [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), might be good choices for Intel CPU BLAS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 80x speedup is plausable if you are comparing DGEMM on a single core of the CPU. I have done a similar benchmark on a `E5-2670 v1 @ 2.6GHz` and I got the following results for double precision DGEMM with Intel MKL (which should give a good upper bound on performance)

- single core : 25 GFlops
- eight cores : 169 GFlops

[the source code for my benchmark is on github](https://github.com/bcumming/gemm)

The Ivy Bridge processor that you are testing with does not have FMA, like the Sandy Bridge I use, and has nearly the same turbo frequency, so I expect single core performance to be similar.

I haven't benchmarked DGEMM on a K40, but in my experience you get close to the peak performance for DGEMM on NVIDIA Keplar GPUs. Peak on a K40 is 1660 GFlops, which is 66x times faster than my single core results... the same ballpark as your observed 80x.

The larger speedup you see might be because you are using single core performance of a DGEMM that is slower than a very highly tuned implementation like MKL. To get a more representative benchmark you will have to

- use a more optimized DGEMM implementation for your host benchmark (try MKL if it is available)
- use all 10 cores of the CPU

Comment: Note that a more up to date comparison is against a Haswell (Xeon v3). For the same benchmark on a Haswell 12-core processor gets 489 GFlops, due mostly to the dual issue FMA introduced in the Xeon V3 processors.